# What are some useful third-party SSIS components (data flow or control flow)?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, components

The number of products out there right now still seems to be slim.

Answer (score 2):

[Konesans Row Number Transformation](http://www.sqlis.com/post/Row-Number-Transformation.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I've had good success using [TableDifference](http://www.sqlbi.com/Projects/TableDifference/tabid/74/language/en-US/Default.aspx) for data warehousing scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

The [Konesans Trash Destination Adapter](http://www.konesans.com/trashdest.aspx) can be very useful during development.

Comment: @Siva Why?  Each is a separate component, which could be assessed differently.

Comment: @Siva Each answer should be cohesive in some way.  There are cases when I post different options in the same answer, but there are also cases where I have used completely different approaches or sometimes if I revisit a question and the answer is very different I will post it as a separate answer, which better indicates that it is a completely different and later approach.